# ViewModel and process death

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

Why it is recommend to use the [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel) architecture component if it does not handle process death?

For example, if I save state with [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)), the state persists both for configuration change and process death while [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel) only survives configuration change. To survive process death, I need to get the state from the [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel) and use the same [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)) mechanism.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why it is recommend to use the ViewModel architecture component if it does not handle process death?
>
> What am I missing?

You were right until January 2020 when, finally, Google released [androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate) and then made the AndroidX Activity, Fragment and Navigation latest library versions provide [SavedStateViewModelFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/SavedStateViewModelFactory) as the default [ViewModelProvider.Factory](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.Factory).

Now you can provide a [SavedStateHandle](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/SavedStateHandle) into your [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel) which can help with persisting/restoring stuff across process death.

```
class MyViewModel(private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): ViewModel() {
    val someState: MutableLiveData<String> = savedStateHandle.getLiveData("someState")
}
```

or

```
class MyAndroidViewModel(application: Application, private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val someState: MutableLiveData<String> = savedStateHandle.getLiveData("someState")
}
```

And these would *just work* via their default constructors as `SavedStateViewModelFactory` creates them via reflection.

If you need a `SavedStateHandle` and also additional parameters, then instead of using a default `ViewModelProvider.Factory`, you can instead extend from `AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory` that will give you a `SavedStateHandle` that actually works and persists/restores across process death automatically.

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, myAbstractSavedStateViewModelFactoryImpl).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

Or with KTX things

```
private val viewModel by viewModels { myAbstractSavedStateViewModelFactoryImpl }
```

You can also scope ViewModels to a Jetpack Navigation's NavGraph, that's a bit trickier but doable:

```
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> SavedStateRegistryOwner.createAbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(
    arguments: Bundle,
    crossinline creator: (SavedStateHandle) -> T
): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    return object : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(this, arguments) {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(
            key: String, modelClass: Class<T>, handle: SavedStateHandle
        ): T = creator(handle) as T
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Fragment.navGraphSavedStateViewModels(
    @IdRes navGraphId: Int,
    crossinline creator: (SavedStateHandle) -> T
): Lazy<T> {
    // Wrapped in lazy to not search the NavController each time we want the backStackEntry
    val backStackEntry by lazy { findNavController().getBackStackEntry(navGraphId) }

    return createViewModelLazy(T::class, storeProducer = {
        backStackEntry.viewModelStore
    }, factoryProducer = {
        backStackEntry.createAbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(
            arguments = backStackEntry.arguments ?: Bundle(), creator = creator
        )
    })
}
```

Then

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    private val mySharedViewModel by navGraphSavedStateViewModels(R.id.registration_graph) { handle ->
        MySharedViewModel(handle)
    }
}
```